# Append lines in div with textarea values using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having code that can append lines depending on comma-separated values in textarea. But I want to show other values with these lines from another textarea. For example, in another textarea I will write peak-123, peak-342, peak-421, peak232, peak748. Now I want to show peak-123 with 20, peak-342 with 45, peak-421 with 60 and so on. Please take a look at my code,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.match').on('input', updateMatch)
  $('.match').trigger('input')
});

function updateMatch() {
  $('.matchi').html($(this).val().split(',').map(e => `<div class='peak' style='left:${e.trim()}%'>${e.trim()}</div>`).join(''));
}
```

```css
.peak {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='match'>
20, 45, 60, 85, 95
</textarea>
<textarea class='match-d'>
peak-123, peak-342, peak-421, peak232, peak748
</textarea>
<div class='matchi' style='position:relative;background:#eee;padding-top:18%' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could add the `peak-x` values to each `peak` div using the index. That's if the values are in order. Meaning that the first `.match` ( eg 20 ) is corresponding to the first `.match-d` ( eg peak-123 )  and so on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.match').on('input', updateMatch)
  $('.match').trigger('input')
 $('.match-d').on('input', () =>  $('.match').trigger('input'))
});

function updateMatch() {
 const peaksValue = $(".match-d").val().split(',')
  $('.matchi').html($(this).val().split(',').map((e, index) => `<div class='peak' style='left:${e.trim()}%'>${e.trim()}<div class="peak-value">${peaksValue[index] ? peaksValue[index]: ''}</div></div>`).join(''));
 
}
```

```css
.peak {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
}
.peak-value {
  margin-top: auto
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='match'>
20, 45, 60, 85, 95
</textarea>
<textarea class='match-d'>
peak-123, peak-342, peak-421, peak232, peak748
</textarea>
<div class='matchi' style='position:relative;background:#eee;padding-top:18%' />
```

Comment: Sir, it is working fine when load, but when I add some value in first textarea or edit some peak in second area then it is not updating

Comment: @Dinesh Well, you just have to adapt the solution a little bit. Check the updated answer